# Prime Walls Before or After Compound/Mud Repairs? - Water Stains

Tags: paint, repainting, primer

Is it ok to prime the walls before I do some mud/compound filling and repairs? I would like to put a full coat of BIN primer (Shellac Based) on the room to help with any possible odors and then get a good coat on for painting.

Is it typically ok to prime first, then do the compound touch ups? Nail holes, small cracks above doorway, a few ceiling cracks from settling, some minor tape and mesh work, etc. I've done it both ways but never on an entire floor. I have already done the prep and widened any nail holes or cracks to hold mud, scraped and sanded little bits from crappy rollers and paint jobs of the past. Its now ready to either be filled/patched with compound and primed.  My goal is to get a full coat of BIN primer on as a sealer of sorts for potential odors since the place is old.

Or am I better off doing all the patch work, then getting the BIN coat on? I realize if I do the BIN first that I'll have to go back over the patched compound/joint compound areas to get a coat on them as well.

I know there are all sorts of products on the market as a primer to seal in odors and give a good base. I've had good luck with BIN Shellac even though its not super popular for this, but I'm going this route for the 1st primer coat.

Any issues with the mud/joint compound bonding to BIN shellac primer? My guess is it will bond to the BIN primer just as good or possibly better since the existing paint seems like its possibly semi-gloss or a sheen below it that gives somewhat of shine.

Comment: My personal rule is "patch first, paint later"  that way you can be sure your patches are solid and smooth.  If there is any texture needed, that should also be done before any priming or painting.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I see that may be better so then I can seal it all in at once and won't have to go back and prime the patched areas.

Comment: The most important part of a paint job is the prep work. Stopping in the middle of painting to fix up the prep work is a major hassle.  _Intending_ to stop in the middle of the paint job to fix up the prep work seems... counterproductive.

Comment: @FreeMan Another vote to do the mud/compound work first before priming. Noted, planning to go this route.